# Нужно изменить количество видимых слайдов при достижении определенной ширины экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

Есть самый обычный слайдер в котором есть 3 видимых слайда, при адаптации столкнулся с такой проблемой, что нужно изменить количество видимых слайдов на экране с 3 на 2.
Пробовал искать в гугле, читать документацию, но не нашел решение.

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 31,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о swiperjs то там есть параметр breakpoints:
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-breakpoints

```
breakpoints: {
    768: {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 18,
    },
    992: {
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 25,
    }
}
```